# $\pi:\Bbb P^1_k\to \text{Spec}(k)$ then is $\Bbb L\pi^*\tilde{k}\cong \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}[0]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, derived-functors

Let $\pi:\Bbb P^1_k\to \text{Spec}(k)$. Am I correct that $\Bbb{L}\pi^*\tilde{k}$ is just $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1_k}[0]\in D_{\text{qc}}(\Bbb P^1_k)$? I saw $\Bbb{L}\pi^*\tilde{k}$ being talked about in some lecture notes, but I was confused why this wasn't identified with $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}[0]$.

Here is my reasoning:

1. I think $\tilde{k}$ is just $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(k)}$,
2. I think that for any scheme map $\pi:X\to Y$ it is true that $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_Y\cong \mathcal{O}_X$ (as $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules),
3. I think that $\tilde{k}$ is free so projective, so $0\to \tilde{k}\to \tilde{k}\to 0$ is a projective resolution with augmentation map of $\tilde{k}$,
4. I think this means $\Bbb L\pi^*\tilde{k}$ is just $\pi^*(\tilde{k}[0])= [\dots \to 0\to \pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(k)}\to 0\to\dots] = \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}[0]$.

Is anything wrong. Thanks! I am newbie to algebraic geometry and only self study.

Comment: No, nothing’s wrong. The pullback $ \pi^* $ is even exact in this case.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Hello, thank you for your response. Is it normal for algebraic geometers to not simplify things as they go? Why call this $\mathcal{E}$ in all the computations if it is obviously the structure sheaf? 

Also, is $\pi^*$ exact because every short exact sequence in $\text{QCoh}(\text{Spec}(k))$ splits, and the pullback commutes with coproducts? Is a more general fact true that and right exact functor which commutes with coproducts, out of an abelian category for which every short exact sequence splits, is an exact functor?

Comment: Why I think the more general statement is true in my comment. Right exact functors are by definition additive functors. Additive functors must preserve biproducts, and must in particular preserve the projection and inclusion maps of the biproducts. If every short exact sequence splits, it is simply expressing one inclusion into a biproduct, followed by a projection from that biproduct. These are preserved by the right exact functor. Actually it sounds like this implies that any additive functor at all from an abelian category in which all short exact sequences split is exact.

Comment: Oh, that is true. See here https://mathoverflow.net/a/408322

Comment: You can also see that $\pi^*$ is exact because $\pi$ is a flat morphism.